# How do I keep my dynamically-loaded jQuery tabs shut until someone clicks on them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>



<div class="demo">

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Address</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div id="dynamicContent">
                John Doe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            Cupertino, California
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

I'm loading `dynamicContent` using an ajax call after page load.

When the data is loaded, the nice colored, styled tabs at the top of the div are replaced with the unordered list:

```
- Name
- Address
```

I tried resetting the tabs to be unselected after the ajax calls have completed:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: -1 });
```

But that doesn't work.

Anything else to try?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `{selected: -1}` . See the [`working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/XarBs/). Here I'm loading name tab using `AJAX` & displaying documentation info tab of jsfiddle site.

I guess your stylesheets or classes are being overwritten by ajax response causing elimination of tab effect.

Just in FF + Firebug, inspect your unordered list after your content gets loaded by AJAX and check its classes.